# Github pages only works on first repository, won't work on new project

Tags: github, github-pages

I create a repository and renamed it to username.github.io, which worked. I decided I do not want to use that repository for my github pages, so I renamed it to something else, created a second repository, then set that new repository to have the github pages name. When I try going to the url, it doesn't work. But when I set put the name back on my first repository, it works again, indicating that my github pages is locked to the first repository that I used it on.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This [thread suggests](https://github.community/t/how-long-does-github-forward-renamed-moved-repos/582) that, from GitHub support:

> We keep redirects for moved and renamed repos indefinitely, but new repos take priority over redirects.
> That means if a new repo is created at an old location, the redirects will break in favor of displaying the new repo, for as long as that new repo exists.

If it does not work in you case (after, say, 24 hours), you should contact the GitHub support to ask why the new `https://github.com/username/username.github.io` is not taken  into account when accessing `https://username.github.io`.